# discord.py rewrite | Implementing currency

Tags: python, dictionary, discord.py

Okay, so I have been wanting to try adding currency to my bot for a while. So, I put my head down and started today, but I am having some issues. I know I will need to use a dictionary of members, and I have that already: `amounts = {}`. I have got a register command, which adds a member to the dictionary with their ID and amount of currency.

However, this doesn't seem to be a good idea. Whenever I re-open the bot, the dictionary gets reset. I am not too sure how to save my dictionary, and would appreciate some help.

As a reference, this is my registering command:

```
@client.command(name='register',
                aliases=['reg'],
                brief='Registers your account',
                pass_ctx=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        await ctx.send('You have been registered')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You already have an account')
```

I am still a bit of a beginner with dictionaries and discord.py, so sorry if I ask a lot of questions to your answer!

Comment: You can either persist that dictionary to a file whenever you change it, and load it from that file when your bot starts (There are a lot of examples of this in the [tag:discord.py] tag).  The other option is to use a database.  If you do use a database, make sure to use an asynchronous library to connect to it: if you use a blocking library, your bot will randomly fail if operations take too long.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh If I use a `.json` file to save my dictionary, how could I save/load my dictionary? Having troubles with what I find online :/

Comment: Using [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).  `with open('amounts.json', 'w') as f: json.dump(amounts, f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I save my dictionary of users to a `.json` file, and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's worth using external database, nice possibility to learn mongodb for example. PyMongo is a way to start.

Comment: I will give PyMongo a go! Thanks for such a quick response, I will go give it a try now :)